# automating putty login functionality

Tags: putty

I need to login in remote server via putty. I'm writing batch file for this :

**@echo off
start C:\Users\Prateek\Desktop\PUTTY.EXE -ssh -P 22 user@host -pw password**

Then i need to login as sudo su user(say userAdmin) with password, which i need to write in  batch file. I don't know how to change the user in batch command line. I mean what will be  command in batch file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Plink](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html)!
It's made by the people who made Putty and its purpose is for exactly what you try to use putty for in your question.

Plink (PuTTY Link) is a command-line connection tool similar to UNIX ssh. It is mostly used for automated operations.

From the Plink Manual:

> 7.3 Using Plink in batch files and scripts
>
> Once you have set up Plink to be able to log in to a remote server without any interactive prompting (see section 7.2.2), you can use it for lots of scripting and batch purposes. For example, to start a backup on a remote machine, you might use a command like:
>
> plink root@myserver /etc/backups/do-backup.sh
>
> Or perhaps you want to fetch all system log lines relating to a particular web area:
>
> plink mysession grep /~fred/ /var/log/httpd/access.log > fredlog
>
> Any non-interactive command you could usefully run on the server command line, you can run in a batch file using Plink in this way.

[Plink Download Link](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html)